# retrieving multi valued select 'value'

Tags: php, select, multivalue

Can anyone tell me how to get the 'value' of selected items from a multivalued select?

I have the following:

```
    <select id="category" name="category[]" multiple="multiple">';

        /* Select categories */ 
        [...]
        <option value"' . $row->id . '">' . $row->name . '</option>';
```

which would return:

```
                    <option value"1">itemName1</option>
```

Why is the code below giving me the selected text and not their values? What's wrong here?

```
                    $category = $_POST['category'];
        if (count($category) > 0){ 

            foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
                echo  $value . "<br>\n";
            }
        }
```

This is returning `itemName1` and I need the actual `value (1)`

Thank you

Comment: try changing  <option value"1">itemName1</option> to  <option value="1">itemName1</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You have:

```
<option value"1">itemName1</option>
```

while it should be:

```
<option value="1">itemName1</option>
```

Comment: Wow! I def need a break... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

mulple select will return a query like this (name = name and values = int)

```
name=1&name=4&name=99
```

so it return the selected values
the array would look like:

```
array(
    name => array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 99
    )
)
```

ps if you fix the HTML error, you will most likely get a valid result